# PL/SQL - Passing SQL Query to Procedure and generating select list

Tags: sql, plsql, cursor

I'm trying to accomplish what seems so simple, yet I can't get it right. I want to pass an sql query via a parameter to a procedure. In that procedure, I want to loop through the results, and create options for a select list.

I've tried using EXECUTE IMMEDIATELY, cursors, SYS_REFCURSOR, etc, but nothing seems to be quite right. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks!!

```
PROCEDURE Dropdown
(
  nam IN VARCHAR2,
  qry IN VARCHAR2,  /* 'SELECT val, descrip FROM table' */
)
IS
  html VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  html := '<select id="test" name="test">';

  /* ?? */

  html := html || '<option value="' || val || '">' || descrip ||'</option>';


  html := html || '</select>';
  htp.p(html);  
END Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REF CURSOR
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#i7106

```
PROCEDURE exeSelect( sql IN VARCHAR2)
IS
TYPE curType IS REF CURSOR;
cur curType;
val table.val%ROWTYPE;
des table.descrip%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR sql;
    LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO val,des;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        ....
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Oracle Developer is throwing a syntax error at "val table.val%ROWTYPE;". I'm guessing that "table" needs to be replaced with the actual table name? If that's the case, I'm not sure if this will work, because I'm passing in the query via the sql parameter.... ex exeSelect(sql => 'SELECT val, des FROM thetable")

Comment: yes, replace it with your real table name. also, it will work when you passing the query in VARCHAR2 type

Comment: That's the point I'm trying to make.... I'm passing in the entire SQL query as a parameter. I want to execute that and build a dropdown list from the vals/descrips in the query results. The table is not static, and varies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using it for dropdownlists with Key-Description pairs, the answer is to use normal variables and to make both as big as the biggest value you are ever going to query.
Normally that would be an unconstrained number for the key and 50 - 120 characters for the description. But analyse that or take a BIG safety margin!

```
PROCEDURE dropdown( p_name   IN VARCHAR2
                  , p_query  IN VARCHAR2 /* 'SELECT val, descrip FROM table' */
                   )
IS
   TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;

   cur      curtype;

   v_value  NUMBER;
   v_descr  VARCHAR2( 120 );

   html     VARCHAR2( 1000 );
BEGIN
   html  := '<select id="test" name="' || p_name || '">';

   OPEN cur FOR SQL;

   LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO v_value, v_descr;

      html  := html || '<option value="' || v_value || '">' || v_descr || '</option>';
      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
   END LOOP;

   html  := html || '</select>';
   Htp.p( html );
END dropdown;
```